# How to binding value from one variable to others

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, bind

I have 2 variable `masterdata` and `datatoedit`.
`masterdata` have array value and `datatoedit` have object value.

I want to copy data 1 from `masterdata` to variable `datatoedit`, so I write like this:

```
this.datatoedit = this.masterdata[0]
```

But when I edit data from `datatoedit` on form data on `masterdata[0]` also changed.

How to prevent `masterdata[0]` from changed when I edit `datatoedit`?

Comment: Share a detailed introduction related to your question - [js-object-copy-by-value-vs-copy-by-reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19448646/js-object-copy-by-value-vs-copy-by-reference)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use ES6 [Spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to make an object copy:

```js
this.datatoedit = {...this.masterdata[0]}
```

Comment: is this work on vuex state too?, you know some time im copy a state from vuex too..

Comment: The result is the same, if you modify the copied object, the original object will not be updated.

Comment: This can go wrong in case of deeply nested objects.

Answer (score 2):

You can also do this using lodash function clonedeep. It will not copy the references.

```
data_to_edit = _.cloneDeep(masterdata[0])
```

You can now modify data_to_edit as your wish.

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer can go wrong if the `masterdata` elements have nested objects like

```
{
   name: 'John',
   age: 30,
   address: {
       street: 'ChurchStreet',
       city: 'Bangalore',
       state: 'KA'
   }
}
```

```js
    var masterdata = [
        {
            name: 'John',
            age: 30,
            address: {
                street: 'ChurchStreet',
                city: 'Bangalore',
                state: 'KA'
            }
        },
        {
            name: 'Jane',
            age: 26,
            address: {
                street: 'West of Chord',
                city: 'Mumbai',
                state: 'MH'
            }
        }
    ];

    // With spread operator
    var datatoedit = {...masterdata[0]};
    datatoedit.age = 32;
    datatoedit.address.street = 'Infantry Road';

    console.log('With spread operator');
    console.log('masterdata[0]: ' + JSON.stringify(masterdata[0]));
    console.log('datatoedit: ' + JSON.stringify(datatoedit));


    // With Object.assign()
    datatoedit = Object.assign({}, masterdata[0]);
    datatoedit.age = 35;
    datatoedit.address.street = 'Brigade Road';
    console.log('With Object.assign()');
    console.log('masterdata[0]: ' + JSON.stringify(masterdata[0]));
    console.log('datatoedit: ' + JSON.stringify(datatoedit));


    // Now with JSON.parse() and JSON.stringify()
    datatoedit = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(masterdata[0]));
    datatoedit.age = 35;
    datatoedit.address.street = 'West of Chord Road';

    console.log('With JSON.parse() and JSON.stringify()');
    console.log('masterdata[0]: ' + JSON.stringify(masterdata[0]));
    console.log('datatoedit: ' + JSON.stringify(datatoedit));
```

As you can see, in case of nested objects, both spread operator and Object.assign() can go wrong as they do shallow copy.

Combining JSON.parse() and JSON stringify() creates the effect of deep copy and hence it works fine all cases. (Though these functions are not meant for deep copy as such).