# Refrence datatype and primitive datatype in Javascript

Tags: javascript

In the following two snippets :

```
​var person = "Kobe";  
​var anotherPerson = person; // anotherPerson = the value of person​
person = "Bryant"; // value of person changed​
​
console.log(anotherPerson); // Kobe​
console.log(person); // Bryant
```

And if we use Object :

```
var person = {name: "Kobe"};
​var anotherPerson = person;
person.name = "Bryant";
​
console.log(anotherPerson.name); // Bryant​
console.log(person.name); // Bryant
```

The first one logs  "Kobe" for the variable `anotherPerson` but if anotherPerson has reference to the variable person any changes happened in person should also reflect another person right ?

Can any one explain this in details

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is JavaScript a pass-by-reference or pass-by-value language?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/518000/is-javascript-a-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value-language)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first example you have 2 variables referencing to `"Kobe"`. Though by assigning `"Bryant"` to the person variable you are changing the reference of that variable. So in the end you got 2 variables each referencing to another string. Since primitve types in JS are immutable, there is no way to "change the value of a string". You can only assign a new string.

[image]

In your second example you are only changing the property of the object you are referencing to, though the reference stays the same of course.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A `variable` can hold one of two types of values: primitive values and reference values.

1. `Primitive values` are data that are stored on the stack.
2. `Primitive value` is stored directly in the location that the variable accesses.
3. `Reference values` are objects that are stored in the heap.
4. `Reference value` stored in the variable location is a pointer to a location in memory where the object is stored.
5. `Primitive types` include Undefined, Null, Boolean, Number, or String.

**The basics**

Objects are aggregations of properties. A property can reference an object or a primitive. Primitives are values, they have no properties.

Answer (score 1):

1. *In your first example you are copying the variable's value to a new variable. Therefore 2 variables are created. So the person value is not changed* **(All types except objects define immutable values (values, which are incapable of being changed).)**
2. *In Objects, data will be stored in* **heap (memory)**. *So if you change the value of Objects[key] will change the value of that key in Main object*.

For more insight see:

- http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/webprog/jscript/ch04_04.htm
- [Primitive value vs Reference value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13266616/primitive-value-vs-reference-value)
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures