# Assigning a value to a variable changes value of right hand side

Tags: javascript

I'm new to JavaScript and feel like I must be missing something fundamental here!

I'm creating a function which sorts a list of integers `list` and returns the minimum value `listSort[0]`.

```
function sortNumber(a,b) {
    return a - b;
}

var min = function(list){
    console.log(list[0]);
    var listSort = list.sort(sortNumber);
    console.log(list[0]);
    console.log(listSort[0]);
    return list[0];
}
```

Can anyone explain why the value of `list[0]` changes after `list.sort(sortNumber)` is assigned to `listSort`  ?

Thanks!

Comment: [`Array.prototype.sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort): "The sort() method sorts the elements of an array **in place** and returns the array. The sort is not necessarily stable. The default sort order is according to string Unicode code points."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **sort()** function directly changes the array to which is applied. For example:

```
myArray.sort();
```

directly changes the content of myArray.
If you do not want to change the content of the original array you need to use a cloning function:

```
function mySortingFunction(list){
   var newList = myCloningFunction(list);
   newList.sort();
   return newList;
}
```

There are several ways to clone an array:
[Javascript fastest way to duplicate an Array - slice vs for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3978492/javascript-fastest-way-to-duplicate-an-array-slice-vs-for-loop)

If you use AngularJS you can simply write:

```
var newList = angular.copy(list);
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the minimum value of an Array, better use `Math.min`

```
var list = [4,2,4,2,6,5,2,4,3,5,2];

var min = Math.min.apply(null, list);
```

Answer (score 0):

If i'm right, it's because when you use your assignment, you are executing list.sort(sortNumber) and so list change as per the assignment function.

Sooo... read like this : 
- list.sort(sortNumber) => List change
- list is assigned to listSort

Despite this fact, I think you're going to far to find the min value.  :P

Comment: Is there away of assigning the value without executing the sort? Or perhaps I just need to do
`listSort = list; 
listSort.sort(sortNumber);`
of course - I probably should do away with listSort altogether in this example, but mostly I want to understand how the assignment works

Comment: Hm.. I don't really know if there is a way to assign the value without executing the sort. (Except for your proposal, this is what I will do in this case)

One way is to rewrite a function that will return the value like "sort(list, sortNumber)" where you can do all the treatments.

Comment: @Chilliontop `listSort = list; listSort.sort(sortNumber);` is the same as `listSort = list.sort(sortNumber)` (relating to the result) -> [Primitive value vs Reference value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13266616/primitive-value-vs-reference-value)