# Are primitive / reference types stored on the heap or on the stack?

Tags: javascript

What determines the storage type in JS? Does it have anything to do with the primitive vs reference types?

I'm coming from the C++ / python background. Reading the answers and comments to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13266616/primitive-value-vs-reference-value), I have encountered a few mutually incompatible (and even internally inconsistent) statements:

From the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13266769/336527):

> - `Primitive values` are data that are stored on the **stack**.
> - `Primitive value` is stored directly in the location that the variable accesses.
> - `Reference values` are **objects** that are stored in the **heap**.
> - `Reference value` stored in the variable location is a pointer to a location in memory where the object is stored.

From the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13266616/primitive-value-vs-reference-value#comment75759398_13266769) on it:

> Whether values are stored on the stack or heap is not determined by their type in JS. It depends on the lifetime of the variable it is stored in (affected by scopes and especially closures, and depending upon the analytical capabilities of the engine).

From the highest voted answer:

> JavaScript doesn't have a stack or a heap. It's a dynamic language and all the variables in JavaScript are dynamic. [...] All the values (primitives and objects) in JavaScript are allocated from the heap. Even the variables themselves are allocated from the heap.

Could someone please clarify or refer me to a technically correct explanation? If the approach is implementation-dependent, I'd appreciate references to the differences in implementation.

Comment: This is a complicated question, and it is implementation-dependent. How an engine deals with variables, is up to the engine, as long it adheres to the Ecma standard etc. For instance V8 has a heap, but also something called "context", and a stack. Where variables are stored depends on a number of things, closures, scope, type etc. As someone who is learning JS, this is generally not something you'd ever have to worry about when writing JS.

Comment: @adeneo Understood, ty. If you have references that would go into those details, could you pls post them here? Also, I removed the "learning" part because it's misleading; I meant that this is precisely the part of JS that I'm trying to figure out now.

Comment: I think the only way to really figure out what's going on, is to read the source code for some of the JS engines, and even then I think it would be hard to figure why something goes where, unless you actually work on creating the JS engines. It seems like complicated stuff.

Comment: @adeneo Ah, I see. So in C++ terms, all JS objects can be thought of as having [dynamic storage duration](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration), except deallocated by the garbage collector instead of manually? (And below that level of abstraction, the details are up to implementation?) That would be identical to python AFAICT.

Answer (score -3):

In JavaScript, primitive types (such as numbers, strings, and booleans) are typically stored on the stack, while objects (reference types) are stored on the heap.

Comment: There is a difference between string literals and string objects https://levelup.gitconnected.com/bytefish-vs-new-string-bytefish-what-is-the-difference-a795f6a7a08b