# Deleting an object's property also delete similarly named property from other objects

Tags: javascript

In JavaScript, if you do this

```
var x = {
    "propname with whitespace": "val1",
    "other propname": "val2"
};

var y = x;
```

and then do this

```
delete y["propname with whitespace"];
```

Will cause `x` to also lose its `propname with whitespace` property. How to delete a property from `y` without affecting `x` while still supporting whitespaces in a property name?

Comment: both variable keeps reference to the same object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because `x` and `y` are both references to the same value in memory, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13266616/primitive-value-vs-reference-value) StackOverflow question.

However, you can use [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) to create a shallow copy of an object:

```js
var x = {
    "propname with whitespace": "val1",
    "other propname": "val2"
};

var y = Object.assign({}, x);
delete y["propname with whitespace"];

console.log(y);
```

Comment: You're answer will work in this situation, but cannot perform a deep clone. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign. But still, I learned something new with the Object.assign()

Answer (score -2):

**Edit**
Just ran into a problem where I needed to copy and object and neither my solution below nor the accepted solution worked. This is because neither solution can perform a deepclone (when a property value is set as an object). Check out the warning in the documentation here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign

Correct answer for a deep clone situation would be

```
y = {'a':2,'b':3}
z = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(y))
```

This will solve the deep clone problem: like if `y = {'a':{'c':4},'b':3}`

**End Edit**

As Pranav put in the comments, both variable reference the same object. So what happens to one, happens to the other. To fix this you would have to create a copy of y without it referencing x:

```
y = {'a' : 2,'b': 3}
z = Object.keys(y)
let x = {}
z
for (i in z) {
  x[z[i]] = y[z[i]]
}
```

Now:

```
delete y["a"]
y = {"b":2}
```

And:

```
x = {"a":1, "b":2}
```

The big takeaway here is that you have to create new object that looks exactly like y, but that doesn't reference y.

Comment: Your example is not working, and the use of `for..in` with arrays is not encouraged.

Comment: Whoops, missed the y[z[i]]. Should work now. Shouldn't be a problem to refactor so that it doesn't use for..in (though in this and most cases I don't see the problem. At the heart of is, your question does get answered though...

Comment: why use Object.keys? Just use `for in` on original object to do it old school way

Comment: lol, true, I was doing something else when I came accross this and had object.keys on the brain.

Comment: Also your answer is much better, I don't think I've ever used object.assign