# Where and how is a value's data type stored, in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, c++, v8

In JavaScript, we have 6 primitive data types (each with their own object wrapper) and 1 object data type.

Where / how does v8 store a value's data type?

Comment: You might find the information [in this question's answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13266769/215552) interesting, but what is the practical reason you need to know?

Comment: v8 is pretty complicated and I don't think there's one simple answer. It looks like [here is](https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/master/third_party/inspector_protocol/lib/Values_h.template) one representation of javascript values in the v8 source, though I can't tell whether it's a particularly relevant one.

Comment: I don't understand.  How does this question about JavaScript have any relationship to C++?  I recommend removing the C++ tag.

Comment: Could the downvoters / closer please provide information on why the question was treated in this manner? It is a fair question, one that I have not been able to find an answer to. I am trying to understand how the engine knows what type a value is. Is it in a few bits before the value itself, that tells the engine what the value is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data type is part of the value. The type of JS values is a [sum type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_type) that lets us distinguish the primitive types and objects. For example `typeof` is an operator that lets us access (parts of) the bit that stores the type.

Of course, an optimising compiler is free to drop that information when it can prove that a certain variable will only ever store values of the same type, so in the implementation the information might be moved to an annotation on the variable.

Comment: Thank you. I don't understand why it is voted down. It is an interesting piece of information, which I was not able to find the answer to elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Your only access to these types is with [typeof](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof).

There are more primitive types but they are not visible in a normal JavaScript environment. If you want to see how these are handeld inside the engine I recommand watching [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EhpmNyR2Za0) I coincidently watched today.