# After duplicating an array list object, does it copy modified original array list automatically?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an array list like this

```
private options: Array<any> = [];
private optionsListDuplicate: Array<any> = [];

let data=[{id:"id",name :"name"},{id:"id2",name:"name"}];

for(let i=0;i<data.length;i++){
    this.options.push({
        label:data[i].name,
        value:data[i].id
    });
    this.optionsListDuplicate.push({
        label:data[i].name,
        value:data[i].id
    });
}
```

but when i modify the `options` array object, it modifies `optionsListDuplicate` object as well. Please help me understand why that happens.

I am adding a new list to the existing options object like this

```
this.options.push({
            label:"somelabel",
            value:"someid"
        });
```

I have the requirement that I need to retain the original object. So i did this

```
this.options=this.optionsListDuplicate;
```

but `this.optionsListDuplicate` is having the modified array object

Comment: Thats should not happen. NOTE: I supouse is label:data[i].id

Comment: This should not have happened. How are you modifying **options**?

Comment: How you modify the option array is the **optionsListDuplicate** in the **same loop** ?

Comment: How are you modifying `options` in a way that `optionsListDuplicate` is modified as well?

Comment: what is `data[i].value`, the `data` array you have provided doesn't have that property

Comment: @cyberpirate92 edited the question

Comment: @OscarPaz  i have modified question.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe use `myCopiedArray = Array.from(originalArray);`

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 types of copies

- Shallow copy
- Deep Copy

When you perform a shallow copy, (i,e) something like  `x = y`, x and y refer to the same memory location, so when you change either `x` or `y`, the change will be reflected in both the variables.

**Example**

```
let x = [1, 2, 3]
let y = x;
let z = x.slice(); // or JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(x));

x.push(4);

console.log(y); // prints [1, 2, 3, 4]
console.log(z); // prints [1, 2, 3]
```

To perform a deep copy, you can use the `splice` method in case of an array or `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(x))` in the case of objects.

When a deep copy is performed, the changes in one variable will NOT affect the others.

> but when i modify options array object, it is modifying optionsListDuplicate object as well

In your case, you might be using the following somewhere

```
this.optionsListDuplicate = this.options;
```

Change it to

```
this.optionsListDuplicate = this.options.slice();
// or..
this.optionsListDuplicate = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.options));
```

### [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/shallow-vs-deepcopy)

Comment: tried slice and second method, still its  not working

Answer (score 0):

Well, if your assigning one array to the other, then of course when you modify one, you modify the other.

When you do

```
this.options = this.optionsListDuplicate;
```

You **aren't copying the array**, just creating a new variable that points to it. In fact, by doing this, the old array pointed to by `this.optionsListDuplicate` is lost. I suggest you to read about reference and value types in JavaScript: [Primitive value vs Reference value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13266616/primitive-value-vs-reference-value)

If you want to keep the original array, then you must do:

```
this.optionsListDuplicate = this.options.slice();
```

As, by your code (you are adding elements to `this.options`) I understand that you want `this.optionsListDuplicate` to be the 'original' array.

Of course, now you don't need to initialise both arrays in the `for` statement. In fact, you don't need `for` for anything, it's better if you use `map`:

```js
private options: Array<any>;
private optionsListDuplicate;

let data=[{id:"id",name :"name"},{id:"id2",name:"name"}];

this.options = data.map(item => { label: item.name, value: item.id });
this.optionsListDuplicate = this.options.slice();
```