# Why is input field not getting cleared

Tags: javascript, iife

I have a function which gets input from a set of input field and stores them as an object like this:

```
getinput:function () {
  return{
    type:document.querySelector(domstring.type).value,
    description:document.querySelector(domstring.description).value,
    value:document.querySelector(domstring.value).value,
    heading:document.querySelector(domstring.heading).innerHTML,
  }
},
```

Here domstring is another object which contains the class names of the target fields.
Now I wrote a clearfields function and what I am trying to do is to access the type  object which is a document.querySelector(domstring.type).value and set it to "" so that value is cleared.Here the base iife is called UIcontroller hence I am accessing as UIcontroller.getinput().description
so UIcontroller looks like this :

```
var UIcontroller=(function (){
domstring={
  type:'.add__type',
  description:'.add__description',
  value:'.add__value',
  add__btn:".add__btn",
  heading:".icome__title",
  income_section:".income__list",
  expense_section:".expenses__list"
}
return{
  getinput:function () {
      return{
        type:document.querySelector(domstring.type).value,
        description:document.querySelector(domstring.description).value,
        value:document.querySelector(domstring.value).value,
        heading:document.querySelector(domstring.heading).innerHTML,
      }
    },
  getdom:function () {
    return domstring

  },
  display:function (r,type) {
    var html,newHTML,element;
    if (type=='inc') {
      element=domstring.income_section;
      html="<div class='item clearfix' id='income-0'><div class='item__description'>%description%</div><div class='right clearfix'><div class='item__value'>%valu%</div><div class='item__delete'><button class='item__delete--btn'><i class='ion-ios-close-outline'></i></button></div></div></div>";

    }
    else {
      element=domstring.expense_section;
      html="<div class='item clearfix' id='income-0'><div class='item__description'>%description%</div><div class='right clearfix'><div class='item__value'>%valu%</div><div class='item__delete'><button class='item__delete--btn'><i class='ion-ios-close-outline'></i></button></div></div></div>";
    }
    newHTML=html.replace("%description%",r.description);
    newHTML=newHTML.replace("%valu%",r.valu);
    document.querySelector(element).insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend',newHTML);

  },
  clearfields:function () {
    console.log("Clear");
    UIcontroller.getinput().description="";
    console.log(UIcontroller.getinput().description);
    document.querySelector(domstring.value).value="";
  }

}


})();
```

I tried the following way:

```
clearfields:function () {
console.log("Clear");

//first one
UIcontroller.getinput().description="";

//second one
document.querySelector(domstring.value).value="";
```

}
I understand that first one and second one are basically the same right but first one does not set to blank however second one works fine.
Can somebody explain.

Comment: `UIcontroller` - is this swift?

Comment: that is the iife function like a self executing function.clear and getinput are the return objects

Comment: Setting `description` would not be the same as setting an input's `value` property as they are not referencing the same thing.

Comment: Are you saying `UIcontroller` is an IIFE? I don't see an IIFE in your code. When you call `getinput()` you would be invoking that function. IIFE invokes immediately.

Comment: I have added the IIFE structure in the description.

Comment: @PatrickEvans I just showed this as an example.

Comment: I still don't see an IIFE - they end with `();`.  Either way, you have your answer in what Patrick Evans said. -- oh, now I see it.  You didn't have it there a moment ago.

Comment: I just added the IIFE

Comment: It doesn't matter if this is an example. `description` or whatever is the real code has no ties to `input.value`, you simply are copying a primitive value to another property in the `getinput()` function, changing one doesn't change the other

Comment: Please edit your code to be more readable. It hurts my eyes.

Comment: I added the entire IIFE @adpro

Comment: Ok, as @PatrickEvans said, `description` is the value of the `value` of the element in question. It is not bound to that object. So, changing the value of `description` will not change the `value` of the element you got the value of `description` from. Carefully take a look at which value and `value` I am referring to.

Comment: What I am saying is that description points to the value in the input field using the queryselector().value right.So technically that is equivalent to document.querySelector(domstring.description).value isn't it

Comment: No, it is not pointing to the input field's `value`, it holds a copy of that string value. There is no binding going on, ie changing one does not change the other. This Q/A post might help: [Primitive Value vs Reference Value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13266616/primitive-value-vs-reference-value)

Comment: Is there any way I could access this way using UIController IIFE ? without using the document.queryselector directly

Comment: you could just do `description:document.querySelector(domstring.description)` and then when you need to set the value, `getinput().description.value = ""` as `description` would then hold a reference to the input element, instead of just a primitive value. You would also have to read the value by doing `getinput().description.value` instead of just `getinput().description`