# why assigning value to specific index from returned array from filter method - will directly modify the array

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, filter

I hope I gave it the proper title because it hard to explain but - 
As I know the `filter` method in JS - when you use it , it should return new filtered array follow the rules you give it.

But now I did some experiments and find out an interesting thing - 
If you use `filter` and in same statement you assign specific index in the array to a variable - and then modify it , it will directly modify the original array with the new value assigned! I wondered if it's a feature of `filter` ? or can it be a JS bug? couldn't find and documentation about it so I'm asking here.

CODE:

```js
let objArr = [
    {name:1},
    {name:2},
    {name:3}
]

let newItem = objArr.filter((item) => item.name > 2)[0]

newItem.name = 10;
console.log(newItem); //  { name: 10 }
console.log(objArr) // [ { name: 1 }, { name: 2 }, { name: 10 } ]
```

Comment: the original array has the same object reference as the filtered result. any change affects the original array and the filtered result by design.

Comment: because filter does not do a *deep* copy

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Primitive value vs Reference value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13266616/primitive-value-vs-reference-value)

Comment: @NinaScholz thanks for the explanation! - isn't `filter` should return a new copy of the array and not a ref to the original? Thanks again!

Comment: you get a new array, but with same object references inside.

Comment: @NinaScholz ohh so basically it work as expected - the array is new but the object inside the array is a ref! Thanks it really helped a lot! (: