# When i setDate for one variable another veriable also changed

Tags: javascript

```
var currrentdate = lastDate;
currrentdate = new Date(currrentdate.setDate(currrentdate.getDate() + diffDays));
```

Here i changed only currentdate value. but lastDate value also changed when i set date for currentdate why?

Comment: `currrentDate` and `lastDate` refer to the same object, and `setDate` modifies that object.

Comment: i don't want to change??

Comment: you need to clone `lastDate`, not just assign it to `currentData`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you replace `var currrentdate = lastDate;` this line with `var currrentdate = new Date(lastDate);`.

This should work fine.

Please reply if you need anything else.

Answer (score 0):

Fundamentals of Javascript language - **reference type vs value type**:

[Primitive value vs Reference value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13266616/primitive-value-vs-reference-value)

Read that and search in google "reference type vs value type in javascript" in browser - you will find lots of interesting information.