# The reasoning behind direct link between DOM Element and the variable it is assigned?

Tags: javascript

I am kinda newbie and I really want to understand why the variables we create don't just get the values inside the DOM element, but becomes the DOM element?

Here is some basic code;

```
var elementValues = document.getElementById("p1");
elementValues.style.color = "red";

 // I don't understand why we don't need this step in order to manipulate the DOM.
// document.getElementById.getElementById("p1") = elementValues;
```

Aren't we basically saying to copy the values from DOM element with an id of *p1* and paste them into *elementValues*?

But why the color of DOM element changes when I change the color of *elementValues*? From what I understand it acts like a pointer.

Comment: No, we aren’t saying that, we are saying, “get me a reference to this DOM element”, because that’s what document.getElementById does. Your chosen variable name `elementValues` simply doesn’t “match” what is actually going on.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is JavaScript a pass-by-reference or pass-by-value language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/518000/is-javascript-a-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value-language)

Comment: Also see [Primitive value vs Reference value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13266616/primitive-value-vs-reference-value)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Javascript, Object variables store a reference to the objects. Hence, `document.getElementById` returns a reference. So when you modify the values of `elementsValues`, your are editing the referenced object.

Have a look on [Working with Objects - Comparing Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Comparing_Objects). You could read the whole page also to have an overview.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is like a pointer.
By using `var elementValues = document.getElementById("p1");` you are assigning a reference to the DOM element to the variable. Nothing about the element gets saved to the variable, but "where to find it".

Comment: *but "where to find it"* is a bit confusing for me. The variable is a pointer to the underlying object in memory.