# How do you get an array of object.key(not values, not string, not only keys) from an object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have this object

```
let listItem = {
  name: "Lydia",
  accountId: "HGVe",
  fleetType: "Haulage"
};
```

I want to get an array which will be exactly like this:

```
[listItem.name, listItem.accountId, listItem.fleetType]
```

*The values in the array don't have to be strings or values as you can see.*

So every element of the array is going to be ***VariableName.key*** (not a string).

!!!!To be 100% clear, these 2 results are NOT what I need:

```
["listItem.name", "listItem.accountId", "listItem.fleetType"] // results are strings: WRONG
["Lydia", "HGVe", "Haulage"] // results are values: WRONG
```

As you can see above, the correct array have in each element a reference to the precise **object.key**

Comment: `Object.values(listItem)`.

Comment: Are you saying to want the array to be `['name', 'accountId', 'fleetType']` or `['Lydia', 'HGVe', 'Haulage']` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get all properties values of a Javascript Object (without knowing the keys)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7306669/how-to-get-all-properties-values-of-a-javascript-object-without-knowing-the-key)

Comment: No, I edited the question for clarification.

Comment: So you are wanting to get an array of objects based off the object type and field name?

Comment: Looks like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/342076). Tell us what you want to do by storing those references in `VariableName.key` format.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your edit, you want to store object references of `listItem` object's properties.

```
let listItem = {
  name: "Lydia",
  accountId: "HGVe",
  fleetType: "Haulage"
};
```

But this object's properties are not objects but primitive values. Primitive values don't have a reference. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13266769/2924577) for more information.

You can create a string object using [String](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String) constructor. And use [Object.values()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) to get these values.

```js
let listItem = {
  name: new String("Lydia"),
  accountId: new String("HGVe"),
  fleetType: new String("Haulage")
};

let refs = Object.values(listItem);

console.log(refs);
```

You now have references stored in an array. You can't have `[listItem.name, listItem.accountId, listItem.fleetType]` without them getting evaluated to those references.

---

**Previous Answer:**

You can wrap this object in another object and use [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) to get its name.

Then use `Object.keys()` on original object to get its keys.

```js
let listItem = {
  name: "Lydia",
  accountId: "HGVe",
  fleetType: "Haulage"
};

var obj = { listItem };
var name = Object.keys(obj)[0];
var result = [];

Object.keys(listItem).forEach((key) => {
  result.push(name + "." + key);
});

console.log(result);
```

> So every element of the array is going to be VariableName.key (not a
>   string).

Every value should have a [data type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures). So what would be the data type of these values? They are likely to be strings.

Comment: Thanks @Nikhil, but this code return an array of string. I do not need string, I need the reference to each value with the object reference as prefix, I edited my question to clarify more.

Comment: @AlessandroCatania - See my edited answer. You can get the references of the values as shown in the answer. But you can't have that name prefix because `VariableName.key` gets evaluated and what gets stored is the reference which it points to.