# JavaScript array concat

Tags: javascript, arrays, push, concatenation

I have these two arrays:

```
    let num1 = [[1]];
    const num2 = [2, [3]];
```

I concat these two and create new array:

```
    const numbers = num1.concat(num2);
    console.log(numbers);
    // results in [[1], 2, [3]]
```

Now I push a new value to num1:

```
    num1[0].push(4);
    console.log(numbers);
    // results in [[1, 4], 2, [3]]
```

But if I write:

```
    num1[0] = [1, 4, 5];
    console.log(numbers);
    // results in [[1], 2, [3]]
```

Why reassigning vale to `num1` does not reflect change in numbers array but push method does?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13266616/primitive-value-vs-reference-value

Comment: Almost sure there are 92345623 dupes for this, but still waiting for a proper one. While the above is related, it doesn't really tackle the issue head on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`num1[0]` starts out with a value that is a reference to an array `[1]`

`numbers` copies that value, so has a reference to the same array.

`num1[0].push(4);` *modifies* that array (which you have two references to)

`num1[0] = [1, 4, 5];` modifies the **value** of `num1[0]` replacing the reference to the original array with a reference to a **brand new array**. `numbers` still contains a reference to the original array.

Answer (score 1):

That's because arrays are objects in Javascript. And objects in JavaScript are always references, so when you push an array to another array, you are actually pushing a reference, not a value.

When you concatenate two arrays, it will copy the values (or references) to a new array.

When you set the value of index 0, you are actually replacing that reference, but the old reference still exists in the concatenated array.