# Difference between primitive value and primitive type?

Tags: javascript, heap-memory, stack-memory

I'm always confused with the difference between these two things.
I know primitive values are stored on the stack and reference values are stored on the heap.
But is it accurate to say that *primitive types store primitive values* and vice versa with reference types/values?

Thanks

Comment: [Types are defined in ECMA-262](https://262.ecma-international.org/#sec-ecmascript-language-types), there is no "primitive type". It defines [primitive values](https://262.ecma-international.org/#sec-primitive-value) as a "*member of one of the types Undefined, Null, Boolean, Number, BigInt, Symbol, or String*", everything else is an Object (including functions, which are callable objects).

Comment: You know what the difference between a value and a type is in general? No, a type doesn't store anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm ... maybe you have a confusion with "primitive type". Most of the time **"primitive type"** (or primitive data type) and **"primitive values"** are used to speak the same things: boolean, null, undefined ...

But you can check these links to know more about it and find a better answer:

- [Official Primitive docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Primitive)
- [Primitive values vs Reference values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13266616/primitive-value-vs-reference-value/13268731)