# Memory overhead of typed arrays vs strings

Tags: javascript, memory, v8, typed-arrays

I am trying to reduce the memory usage of a JavaScript web application that stores a lot of information in memory in the form of a large number of small strings. When I changed the code to use `Uint8Array` instead of `String`, I noticed that memory usage went up.

For example, consider the following code that creates many small strings:

```
// (1000000 strings) x (10 characters)
var a=[];
for (let i=0; i<1000000; i++)
    a.push("a".repeat(10).toUpperCase());
```

If you put it in an empty page and let the memory usage settle for a few seconds, it settles at **70 MiB** on Google Chrome. On the other hand, the following code:

```
// (1000000 arrays) x (10 bytes)
var a=[];
for (let i=0; i<1000000; i++)
    a.push(new Uint8Array(10));
```

uses **233 MiB** of memory. An empty page without any code uses about 20 MiB. On the other hand, if I create a small number of large strings/arrays, the difference becomes smaller and in the case of a single string/array with 10000000 characters/entries, the memory usage is virtually identical.

So why do typed arrays have such a large memory overhead?

Comment: well for one on one hand you have an array of strings on the other you have an array of arrays  not quite the same for a more accurate comparison split your strings `a.push("a".repeat(10).toUpperCase().split(''));`

Comment: I compare an array of `String` with an array of `Uint8Array`. I think is a fair way to compare `String` with `Uint8Array`. The outer array is only used to allow me to have multiple `String`/`Uint8Array`.

Comment: And I always thought a string is more like an Uint16Array…

Comment: What specific Chrome version is this? 32-bit or 64-bit?

Comment: It's 64 bit Chromium 60.0.3112.78, under linux

Answer (score 31, accepted):

V8 developer here. Your conclusion makes sense: If you compare characters in a string to elements in a `Uint8Array`, the string will have less overhead. TypedArrays are great at providing fast access to typed elements; however having a large number of small TypedArrays is not memory efficient.

The difference is in the object header size for strings and typed arrays.

For a string, the object header is:

1. hidden class pointer
2. hash
3. length
4. payload

where the payload is rounded up to pointer size alignment, so 16 bytes in this case.

For a `Uint8Array`, you need the following:

1. hidden class pointer
2. properties pointer (unused)
3. elements pointer (see below)
4. array buffer pointer (see below)
5. offset into array buffer
6. byte length
7. length of view into array buffer
8. length (user-visible)
9. embedder field #1
10. embedder field #2
11. array buffer: hidden class pointer
12. array buffer: properties pointer (unused)
13. array buffer: elements pointer (see below)
14. array buffer: byte length
15. array buffer: backing store
16. array buffer: allocation base
17. array buffer: allocation length
18. array buffer: bit field (internal flags)
19. array buffer: embedder field #1
20. array buffer: embedder field #2
21. elements object: hidden class pointer
22. elements object: length (of the backing store)
23. elements object: base pointer (of the backing store)
24. elements object: offset to data start
25. elements object: payload

where, again, the payload is rounded up to pointer size alignment, so consumes 16 bytes here.

In summary, each string consumes `5*8 = 40` bytes, each typed array consumes `26*8 = 208` bytes. That does seem like a lot of overhead; the reason is due to the various flexible options that TypedArrays provide (they can be overlapping views into ArrayBuffers, which can be allocated directly from JavaScript, or shared with WebGL and whatnot, etc).

(It's not about "optimizing memory allocation" nor being "better at garbage collecting strings" -- since you're holding on to all the objects, GC does not play a role.)

Comment: Thanks for the info, quite illuminating. Do you know what is the overhead of `ArrayBuffer`? I was thinking that I could use those instead and then cast them to `Uint8Array` on a per-use basis. It appears that they have smaller overhead. Also, do you know if `ArrayBuffer`/`Uint8Array` carries a significant overhead when stored in `indexedDB`?

Comment: I did some more experiments and measurements and found the following estimates for the costs of different types: `String` 40 bytes/element, `ArrayBuffer` 64 bytes/element, `Uint8Array` 176 bytes/element.

Comment: An empty `ArrayBuffer` should be 9 pointers large, if I counted correctly, plus it needs a backing store which has a 4-pointer header, so the total is (9+4)*8 = 104 bytes. -- 
Saying that strings use "40 bytes/element" isn't quite accurate. A string of n characters uses 24 + n bytes: 1 byte per character plus 24 bytes object header. Similarly, a Uint8Array with n elements uses 112 + n bytes: 1 byte per element plus 112 bytes object header.

Comment: @jmrk +1 That’s good to know, I deleted my answer (which was obviously a guess based on a flimsy reading of d8 output). Can you point to any resources, other than the code base itself, for learning more about v8 internals? Thanks!

Comment: @jmrk Sorry, by "element" I meant an element of the "outer" array i.e. a `String`/`ArrayBuffer`/`Uint8Array`. All of those elements were 10 chars/bytes long (so n=16 b/c of rounding). As you can see, my empirical measurements match your calculations for `String`. But they differ for the other 2. One possible explanation is that for `Uint8Array` you pay the overhead for `Uint8Array` plus the overhead for the underlying `ArrayBuffer`. This would explain the 112 (=176-64, see my numbers above) that you calculated. So the only thing I can't explain is the 64 bytes for `ArrayBuffer` that I got.

Comment: @RobM. Sorry, nope, for internals like this the source is the source of truth. 
@safsaf32: Yes, good point, it looks like the `ArrayBuffer` is always created right away when the `Uint8Array` is created (I think it used to be materialized only when code required it). I had overlooked that. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: @jmrk Aren't strings encoded with UCS2 in JS, where every element needs 16 bit? Or is there an optimisation for ASCII-only strings amongst the various special representations?

Comment: @Bergi Yes, there are one-byte strings and two-byte strings in V8.

Comment: note that the problem with typed arrays is that they are slower to create than arrays and strings since they are not a primitive.

Answer (score 3):

The typed arrays are not supposed to be used that way.

If you want high memory efficiency, use just one typed array to hold all of your integer numbers. Instead of use a huge number of arrays to hold your integer numbers due to low level reasons.

Those low level reasons are related to how much overhead is need to hold one object in memory, and that quantity depends on a few aspects like immutability and garbage collection. In this case hold one typed array has higher overhead than hold one simple string. Thats why you should pay that price one time only

You should take advantage of:

```
var a = [];                       for (let i=0; i<1000000; i++) a.push("1");
var b = new Uint8Array(10000000); for (let i=0; i<1000000; i++) a[i] = 1;
// 'b' is more memory efficient than 'a', just pay the price of Uint8Array one time
// and save the wasted memory in string allocation overhead
```

Comment: Good point, +1. One downside of that approach is that it is less friendly to `indexedDB` and it makes it harder to manage the big array when the data set gets modified.