# Armadillo C++ linear algebra library : How to create vector of boolean

Tags: vector, boolean, armadillo

Recently I started using Armadillo C++ library. Given my C++ coding skills are not that great, I found this very friendly for linear algebra. I am also using that along with my matlab to speed things up for many of reconstruction algorithm.

I do need to create a vector of boolean and I would prefer using this library rather than . However, I could not figure out how to do it. I tried using uvec; but, documentation seems to indicate that it can not be used with boolean.

Any help would be appreciated.

Regards,
Dushyant

Comment: Armadillo generally uses `umat` and `uvec` to represent matrices and vectors that store logical values.

Comment: I have the same question and expect an answer to have `vector <bool>`, which takes less space then `vector <char>`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider using a matrix `uchar_mat` which is a typdef for `Mat<unsigned char>`, it should consume the same amount of memory as a matrix of boolean values.

The [Armadillo documentation](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#Mat) of version 7.8 states that a matrix `Mat<type>`, can be of the following types: 
`float`, `double`, `std::complex<float>`, `std::complex<double>`, `short`, `int`, `long`, and `unsigned` versions of `short`, `int`, and `long`. The code on GitHub however contains `typedef Mat <unsigned char> uchar_mat;` in the file [include/armadillo_bits/typedef_mat.hpp](https://github.com/conradsnicta/armadillo-code/blob/unstable/include/armadillo_bits/typedef_mat.hpp) so you should also be able to use `uchar_mat`.

You will not save any memory by creating a matrix of `bool` values compared to a matrix of `unsigned char` values (a `bool` type consumes 8 bits). This is because [in C++ every data type must be addressable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2064550/c-why-bool-is-8-bits-long); it must be at least 1 byte long so that it is possible to create a pointer pointing to it.

Comment: `vector <bool>` takes a lot less memory then `vector <char>`

Comment: @kirill_igum are you referring to `std::vector<bool>`? This is a specialized version of `std::vector` which optimizes for space. I do not think a similar mechanism exists in the Armadillo library. So, indeed, depending on what you want to do you could be better off using the `std` namespace vector class.

Comment: I knwo this aswer is old, but when I knwo look at the armadillo doc, there is no char type available, How can I accomplish it now?

Comment: You are right the documentation does not mention `char` any longer. There still seems to be support for it in the code though. What error did you get when trying to use `Mat<unsigned char>`?

Comment: There is even a statement `typedef Mat <unsigned char> uchar_mat;` in the file [include/armadillo_bits/typedef_mat.hpp](https://github.com/conradsnicta/armadillo-code/blob/unstable/include/armadillo_bits/typedef_mat.hpp) so you should also be able to use `uchar_mat`.