# Looping over BOOLs in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, for-loop, boolean

Is it safe to loop over Objective-C BOOLs like so:

```
for (BOOL flagA = NO; flagA <= YES; flagA++)
    for (BOOL flagB = NO; flagB <= flagA; flagB++)
        // ...
```

I'd like to use this to cycle through all relevant permutations of flags in a `XCTestCase`.

But it appears as if `YES++` is still `YES` at least on some platforms (hence leading to an infinite loop e.g. on iPhone 6 Plus simulator) whereas I would have expected that `BOOL` would just be treated as `int` (and hence `YES++` becoming `2`).

Do I have to loop over `int`s (my best guess) instead, or can the use of `BOOL` be salvaged in some convenient way?

Comment: Why don't you just use ints and then use integers as bools?

Comment: @Sulthan See last line in Q. So is this the way to go? Do you know why `BOOL` (apparently) works differently (in terms of `++`) on different platforms?

Comment: I can't currently see a mistake in your code because `YES` should be 1 and `NO` should be 0 and `BOOL` should be signed char but you should never compare booleans with `<=` or incrementing booleans. Those operations are something undefined.

Comment: The code in question actually works on my machine.

Comment: I'm confused about `YES++`. Does `1++` equal `2`, or is it only valid for variables?

Comment: @Sulthan On an iPhone 6 Plus simulator? Here it does not (Xcode running on MacBook Pro.)

Comment: @NicolasMiari `YES++` was just meant as shortcut for `flag = YES; flag++`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are all missing the point here. Drux is asking why can't he increment over BOOL, while it should be a char (8 bit value), which is perfectly incrementable.

The Answer is very easy. BOOL is sometimes a char and sometimes a `bool` depending on the target. From `objc.h` file:

```
#if !defined(OBJC_HIDE_64) && TARGET_OS_IPHONE && __LP64__
typedef bool BOOL;
#else
typedef signed char BOOL;
```

If you iterate over a `bool` you will get value of `1` maximum.

**EDIT:**

> Can you please add a reference to where the semantics of ++ for bool are specified? - Drux

Even though that `bool` has to be 8 bits minimum, it can't have any other value than `0` or `1`. Why ? Because `bool a = 3` (bool equal operator) converts `3` into a `bool` value, which is `true` which is `1`.

So `bool a = true; a++` is the same as `bool a = 2;` which makes `a` have a value of `1`

Comment: We weren't missing a point. We told him that what he's doing is not defined.

Comment: But you didn't tell him why.

Comment: The reason is not the actual macro implementation, the reason is the logic behind it. It's a boolean, so there is no increment defined. It's a boolean, so there is no comparison defined.

Comment: So, `bool` (**not** `BOOL`) is defined as a special, 1-bit type? And that makes it "wrap around" modulo 2? Didn't know that!

Comment: I think you nailed it. Can you please add a reference to where the semantics of `++` for `bool` are specified?

Comment: @NicolasMiari I wish it was that easy. bool can't be 1 bit, because you can't create a pointer to 1bit. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2064550/c-why-bool-is-8-bits-long

Comment: I see... but it still can be equal to 1 maximum. I wonder what under-the-hood, implementation-dependant mechanisms go into guaranteeing that.

Comment: @Sulthan: Incrementing a bool _is_ defined. It changes 0 to 1, and it leaves 1 unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

I think @Sulthan means something like this (made overly explicit on purpose):

```
for(int indexA = 0; indexA <= 1; indexA++){
    for(int indexB = 0; indexB <= indexA; indexB++){

        BOOL flagA = (indexA == 1) ? YES : NO;
        BOOL flagB = (indexB == 1) ? YES : NO;

        // Use your flags (booleans) here...

    }
}
```

(Of course, you can use just the `int`s in place of booleans in Objective-C, if you want to avoid using too many redundant variables).

**ADDENDUM:** I actually performed a "Jump to definition" in Xcode (OSX project), and the part looks like this:

```
#if __has_feature(objc_bool)
#define YES __objc_yes
#define NO  __objc_no
#else
#define YES ((BOOL)1)
#define NO  ((BOOL)0)
#endif
```

(usr/include/objc/objc.h)

Can't "Jump to Definition" on `__objc_yes` (gives "Symbol Not Found")

Comment: But why is sg. like this even necessary? Isn't `BOOL` just mapped to some type (`unsigned char` perhaps) with more than 1 bit in representation?

Comment: At the very least, I would avoid using booleans as loop variables because it will confuse a bit anyone who has to maintain your code down the road (it isn't something people are used to seeing).

Comment: I know what you mean, but I think that is implementation-dependent and somewhat not guaranteed. If I remeber correctly, `true` is only required to be "non-zero", not necessarily 1 (I could be wrong).

Comment: `__objc_yes` is a compiler literal, see LLVM documentation for it. It gets implicitly translated to `((BOOL)1)` too.

Comment: OK, so it **should** work then. Still, I stand by my opinion that it is bad practice, and he is better off using explicit `int`s as loop variables.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I see would be adding a break in your loop to escape the infinite loop.

Another possibilities is to use simple integer and stop the for loop when `counter == 2`

```
for (BOOL flagA = NO; YES; flagA++) {
    for (BOOL flagB = NO; YES; flagB++) {
        // Do something
        if (flagB)
          break;
    }
    if (flagA)
       break;
}
```

Comment: Yep that would work even with `BOOL`s. (Although I would prefer looping over `int`s in this case -- in which case the breaks are IMO redundant.)

Comment: @Drux Yep I probably would too. But since the question was to find a way to use `BOOL` I just answered with the only possibility I saw.

Comment: Thx, it's appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you're set on operating over `BOOLs`, then instead of:

```
for (BOOL flagA = NO; flagA <= YES; flagA++)
    for (BOOL flagB = NO; flagB <= flagA; flagB++)
        // ...
```

You should really be doing something this (though it is not what you want):

```
for (BOOL flagA = NO; flagA != YES; flagA = !flagA)
    for (BOOL flagB = NO; flagB != flagA; flagB = !flagB)
        // This is the only safe way to 'iterate' BOOLs
```

The behaviour, `(BOOL)++` is not well-defined* as a `BOOL` can only be `YES` or `NO`. What you really should be doing is casting your `BOOL` to an `int`, and iterating over that, or refactoring your loop entirely to use `int` types.

The problem with casting your `BOOL` values to `ints` is, as you have pointed out, `BOOL` is typedef'd to something with only 8 bits of information*, therefore it only makes sense to have 255 iterations. In fact in more recent times, `BOOL` is not cast-able at all because it is defined as a compiler intrinsic (`objc_bool`, which can have values `__objc_yes` and `__objc_no`). `__objc_no++` has no meaning.

**TL;DR** My (strong) suggestion would be to refactor your code so you are iterating over integers, and inspecting `BOOLs` within each iteration. Whether you cast your `BOOL` values, or refactor your loop is up to you, but iterating over `BOOL` values in the way you have indicated is both unsafe and (now, because of that) unsupported.

---

* In past years, the implementation details of `BOOL` were obvious (namely a cast to an unsigned char). With the advent of compiler intrinsics, the details are hidden (though they are likely the same). The reason they are now hidden is because you're really not supposed to rely on them, and the easiest way to stop people relying on them is to hide them from the compiler altogether.

Comment: Why do you think the 2nd version is not what I want? It looks fine to me. (Although I agree hat looping over `int`s is the better option).

Comment: It seems that with this loop you won't even enter it once. flagA == flagB at first iteration of the second loop, then flagA == YES and you won't enter the first loop again.