# Why int8 works like char (C++) (Visual Studio 2015)

Tags: c++, char, int, visual-studio-2015

I'm trying to find the smallest int type in C++. I read that there are no types which use less than a byte, [because is the minimum addressable size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2064550/c-why-bool-is-8-bits-long). The smallest one I found is int8_t, or _int8 visual studio type. I tried to use both, but the program stores the values as chars. There are a way to use this types as integers? Or even, if there are a way to use smaller types (2 bits (signed) would be perfect XD, I need to store only -1, 0 and 1), or any other numeric byte type.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What you are asking is:

*is there a way to store a char so that it is not a char?*

Comment: What does "stores the values as chars" mean? It's not clear what your objection to using `int8_t` is.

Comment: I'm not much a pro on VS, but your _int8 is simply a char with a different name to improve code readability. For smaller type, use std::bitset maybe, depending on your needs

Comment: If you only want to store 0 and 1, you can use an implementation similar to `std::vector<bool>`, where 8 bit values can be stored in one byte. Otherwise, you would have to come up with a mini hack to make it work for more values.

Comment: Or to put it the other way, a char is simply a signed [usually] 8-bit integer.  You _can_ store 2-bit entities, but only within a larger whole (search _struct_ and _bitfield_ -- for example [this wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_field)).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standard gives you the following types:

- `signed char`
- `unsigned char`

(with `char` being equivalent to one of these)

And your fixed-width `int8_t`, `uint8_t` on an 8-bit system are simply *aliases* for these.

**They are all integers already.**

Your statement "but the program stores the values as chars" suggests a misunderstanding of what values with these types fundamentally *are*. This may be due to the following.

The only "problem" you may encounter is the special-case formatting for these types in the IOStreams sublibrary:

```
const char c = 40;
std::cout << c << '\n';
// Output: "("
```

Since `int8_t` is/may be `signed char`, this is literally the same:

```
const int8_t c = 40;
std::cout << c << '\n';
// Output: "("
```

But this is easily "fixable" with a little integral promotion:

```
const char c = 40;
std::cout << +c << '\n';
// Output: 40
```

Now the stream gets an `int`, and lexically-casts it as part of its formatting routine.

This has to do with the type system and the function overloads provided by the standard library; it has nothing to do with "how the values are stored". They are all integers.

Comment: As you told the problem was the IOStreams representation. I saw the output, and that the processor set 'char' as value type, and didn't know that for all the other operations the chars are intergers.
Thanks a lot ;-)

Comment: Minor side note: while `char` is equivalent to either `signed char` or `unsigned char` in most aspects, it is not an alias (e.g. not typedef) but a distinct type. E.g. you can have 3 overloads: `f(char)`, `f(signed char)`, `f(unsigned char)`.

Comment: @PabloH That's correct. "Is equivalent to", not "is".

Answer (score 2):

> I tried to use both, but the program stores the values as chars.

It doesn't (store the values as chars). In C++, a char value *is* an integer value. The difference to other integer types, is in two places:

- the compiler converts char literals to integers transparently
- the standard library treats char type separately from other integer types (that is, it considers char to represent <strike>letters</strike> text characters, not numbers).

As far as the compiler is concerned, the code:

```
char x = 'A';
```

is equivalent to:

```
char x = 65; // set value to 65 (ASCII code for letter "A")
```

If you look in the debugger at the second definition of `x`, is probable the debugger/IDE will tell you x is 'A'.

> Or even, if there are a way to use smaller types (2 bits (signed) would be perfect XD, I need to store only -1, 0 and 1), or any other numeric byte type.

There is no integer type with a smaller than 8 bits representation.

That said, you can (and probably should) create a custom type for it:

```
enum class your_type: std::uint8_t
{
    negative = -1,
    neutral = 0,
    positive = 1
};
```

Choose values that make sense in the context of your program (i.e. not "negative, neutral and positive").

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [bit field](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/bit_field) with two bits.

Answer (score 1):

With MSVC you could use `#pragma pack(1)` and structs to obtain this.

```
#pragma pack(1)
struct int2 {
    int value:2;
};
#pragma pack()

int main()
{
    int2 a;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        a.value = i;
        std::cout << a.value << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
0
1
-2
-1
0
1
-2
-1
0
1
```

I guess building constructors and operator functions to access the value indirectly shouldn't be a problem.

**EDIT: Improved version with operators:**

```
#pragma pack(1)
template <typename INT_TYPE, int BYTE_SIZE>
class int_x {
    INT_TYPE value: BYTE_SIZE;
public:
    int_x() :value(0) {}
    int_x(INT_TYPE v) :value(v) {}
    operator INT_TYPE() const {
        return value;
    }
    int_x& operator=(INT_TYPE v) {
        value = v; return *this;
    }
    int_x& operator+=(INT_TYPE v) {
        value += v; return *this;
    }
    int_x& operator-=(INT_TYPE v) {
        value -= v; return *this;
    }
    int_x& operator/=(INT_TYPE v) {
        value /= v; return *this;
    }
    int_x& operator*=(INT_TYPE v) {
        value *= v; return *this;
    }
};
typedef int_x<int, 1> int1;             //Range [-1;0]
typedef int_x<unsigned int, 1> uint1;   //Range [0;1]

typedef int_x<int, 2> int2;             //Range [-2;1]
typedef int_x<unsigned int, 2> uint2;   //Range [0;3]

typedef int_x<int, 3> int3;             //Range [-4;3]
typedef int_x<unsigned int, 3> uint3;   //Range [0;8]
#pragma pack()
```

Comment: gcc supports this as well:
https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Structure-Packing-Pragmas.html

Comment: Isn't your approach undefined? As the value is not undefined and you're relying on wrap-around semantics for the demonstration.

Comment: What exactly do you mean? My "demonstration" is only to show the overflow. What do you think is undefined?

Comment: Signed integer overflow.

Comment: `[C++11: 4.7/3]` renders the conversion back to `int2::value` (during your assignment operation) as undefined. Only _unsigned_ integer "overflow" is well-defined (and, as such, is not an overflow at all). Therefore, your program has UB and _strictly speaking_ doesn't demonstrate anything reliably ;)

Comment: Ah. Yes, the overflow itself is UB if the base type is signed. But the overflow in this case was only used to show the range of the int_x specialisation. So the approach itself is defined behaviour but my method to show the behaviour is based in UB.

Comment: Additionally I stated that the (original) approach is based MSVC. Even if behaviour is undefined in the standard it can still be defined or at least work in a comprehensible way for a specific implementation of the standard.

Comment: Yes that's what I said - the demo invokes UB so the whole thing is suspect. _Technically_. :)