# Is it possible to send decimal value(8 bit) in bool ? If Yes then How?

Tags: c++, c++11

[bool is 8 bits long](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2064550/c-why-bool-is-8-bits-long)

As above post describe , bool is 8 bit long.
So is it possible to send value 2 in `bool` variable.
i.e.

> 0000 0010   ->    2

(decimal representation)

eg: `bool x;`

How to send this '2' in above bool variable 'x' ?

Thanks

Comment: you could try `reinterpret_cast<char&>(x) = 2;` But really, you should not use bool at all if you want to set 2 to a variable.

Comment: You could, but once you execute that, the behaviour is undefined.  *Anything* can happen.

Comment: It is 8 bits long on some guy's system. Read the post you linked.

Comment: To be honest, for this question it's sufficient that `bool` is _at least_ 8 bits, and _that_ statement is correct everywhere.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not in C++, no.  A `bool` can hold `true` or `false`.  There is no way to store `2` in a `bool` without first invoking undefined behaviour.  Once you have invoked undefined behaviour, *anything* can happen.  (Including what you expected *except*  when demo'ing to important clients).

Also, a `bool` is not necessarily 8 bits long.  It must be at least as large as a char (because `sizeof(bool)` must be at least 1), and the limits on the range of values which an `unsigned char` can hold means that it must be at least 8 bits.  OTOH, there is nothing to stop an implementation using a `bool` which is larger than `char`, and there actually are implementations where `char` is 32 or 64 bits (DSP chips in the main).

Comment: Plus one for mentioning the demo horror!

Comment: I don't know, but I imagine the std::vector<bool> specialisation could use less than 1 byte per element.

Comment: @Matt: That is true, but it doesn't contain actual `bool` variables (**spit!**).

Comment: @MartinBonner, yep, but it would stop you storing a 2 in it.

Answer (score 6):

> bool is 8 bits long

Not *necessarily* true. All the standards say is that it has to be capable of holding `true` and `false`: its `sizeof` is *implementation defined*. You can deduce that it must be *at least* 1 since the *type* of `sizeof` must be an integral type and it cannot be zero else *pointer arithmetic* on an array of `bool`s would break.

So **don't** attempt to send the value 2 - you're bound to render the behaviour of your program *undefined*.

Comment: Actually, a bool has to be *at least* 8 bits -sizeof is indeed implementation defined, but it has to be at least 1, and char must be at least 8 bits.

Comment: Indeed. I've slipped that in. I still prefer your answer though.